# Why does the chlorine radical attack the carbon-hydrogen bond in methane as apposed to the chlorine - carbon bond in a molecule of chloromethane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

During the propagation step in a free radical substitution for the production of haloalkanes, a chlorine radical attacks the carbon-hydrogen bond in chloromethane. Even though this feels right, and I understand why, I couldn't find much information on the interaction between the Chlorine-carbon bond and the chlorine radical. Why doesn't it break that bond and make $\ce{Cl2}$ and a methyl radical? Is it because the chlorine carbon bond is much stronger than the carbon-hydrogen bond?

Comment: The reaction is exothermic. The C-H bond of methyl chloride is attacked by  chlorine atoms. Higher chlorination products are formed. [Take a look at either of the first two items here](http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/StudyAids.html#Radical).